# Running a PHP script with Elysia CRON

Tags: 7, cron, external-scripts

I want to automatically run a PHP script every 3 hours or so. The script is pretty heavy. It pulls XML data from another website then encodes it into a JSON file to be imported by feeds.  The resulting JSON file is around 250 KB.  I'm trying to set it up with the Elysia CRON module but it keeps saying that I have invalid lines.

`3 * * * * php https://dev-smwdb.pantheonsite.io/sites/all/gen-job-bank/gen-job-bank.php`

What do I need to change? Is this even possible with Elysia? Is there a better solution?

Drupal 7 site built on the Pantheon platform.  No backend access to CRON and PHP execution time limited to 120.

Thanks.

Comment: Cron (and elysia cron) just runs commands. Try your command `php https://dev-smwdb.pantheonsite.io/sites/all/gen-job-bank/gen-job-bank.php` from your workstation. I'm going to guess that it doesn't work.

Comment: That command looks dodgy just at a casual glance - it suggests your webserver is serving back a PHP script as text, which most server configs do not allow, because of the disclosure risk. If you are running the script ON the server, you need the file path (eg. ./var/www/mysite/sites/all/gen-job-bank/gen-job-bank.php), not the URL.

Comment: edited the line to `3 * * * * php /srv/bindings/a4ed884a36c34af7b9c2e5421db8dbec/code/sites/all/gen-job-bank/gen-job-bank.php` still says invalid lines